# Is there a Stack Exchange site where I can ask for Business Processes management?

Tags: support, site-recommendation

I am looking for some standard (or analysis, or research) which covers business processes within a software-development company.

I tried to ask both at https://pm.stackexchange.com/ and http://stackoverflow.com, but my question was declined as off-topic.

Here you can find full text of my question: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33861782/is-there-any-standard-for-business-processes-within-a-software-development-compa

Please advice which Stack Exchange site should I use for my question.

Answer (score 2):

The main problem with your question is that it is effectively a recommendation question. Those don't do well on most sites, including SO.

I am not sure, but maybe [Programmers.SE](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic) is the site to ask. I don't think there is any other site, launched or on Area 51, at the moment suiting your question.

Comment: Thx. There are lots of recommendation questions on every SO site. E.g. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/461618/whats-most-important-when-you-need-to-establish-a-software-development-infrastr?rq=1. OR http://stackoverflow.com/questions/848862/business-rule-and-process-management?rq=1. I think a site with name like ITmanagement.SO would be useful for such a topic.

Comment: That are very old questions under old rules. One is even closed.